# Search and replace all php_short_tag that is <?= and <?

Tags: php, regex, replace, php-shorttags, shorttags

I did not want the hasle of turning on php_short_tag in php.ini and also i wanted to use xml without issues which short tags could introduce, so instead i replaced every occurance of a short tag in the code by using search and replace.

I thought i should share it here since i found many answers that did not work until i tweaked them

1. First search and replace `<?=` with `<?php` NOTE: make sure `<?php`
   has a space after it so that `<?=code` will be `<?php code` and not
   `<?phpcode`.
2. The regex for that is `<[?][\=](?!php)`, check it out at
   [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pqjhZ3L3YCXgB3XN)
3. Then search and replace `<?` with `<?php` NOTE: make sure `<?php`
   has a space after it so that `<?code` will be `<?php code` and not
   `<?phpcode`.
4. The regex for that is `<[?](?!php)`, check it out at
   [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KPYxacaW_1J0xrm_)

Comment: Firstly, this isn't a question. Secondly, the `<?=` tag is not equivalent to `<?php`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make the `=` symbol as optional one.

```
preg_replace('~<\?=?(?!php\b)~', '<?php ', $str);
```

OR

```
preg_replace('~<\?=?(?!php\b)(\w)~', '<?php \1', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wT0iY3/3)

Answer (score -1):

Just a heads up the `<?=` symbol mimics the echo function so i had to udo my change eg:

`<?= __("Key") ?>` was changed to `<?php __("Key") ?>`

This did not output the language so i undid this byt the regex:

`(?<=php)\ (?=__[(])`
`<?php __("Key") ?>` became this `<?php echo __("Key") ?>`